# how to disconnect the method for a signal in qml？

Tags: qt, qml

In QML, in some situations, I need to remove the old method to a signal and redefine a new method to handle the signal, a demo is as following:

```
import QtQuick 2.6
import QtQuick.Window 2.2

Window {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    MouseArea {
        id:mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        onClicked: {
            console.log("11111");
        }
    }


    Text {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        //if(false){
        //}
        // mouse.clicked = null;
        //mouse.clicked.disconnect();

        mouse.clicked.connect(
                    function(){
                        console.log("22222")
                    });
    }

}
```

I connect a new function, however it will show **both "11111" and "22222"**, seems it add a new function to handle the signal.

I  tried set "**mouse.clicked = null**", still doesn't work.

I also tried disconnect the method,like as following:

```
MouseArea {
    id:mouse
    anchors.fill: parent
    onClicked:say()
}

Component.onCompleted: {
    mouse.clicked.disconnect(say);
    mouse.clicked.connect(
                function(){
                    console.log("22222")
                });
}

function say(){
    console.log("11111");
}
```

Still print both "11111" and "22222", how can I remove the old methond and redefine the method in **Component.onCompleted()**?

**update on 2017-6-13:**

Thanks, guys.I also use connections,still cannot disconnect as I use qt5.6.1, there is no enable property :( . if we use explicitly connect() function, it works. but in my case, I think I can't connect a method , I need to check some If situations to define whether I need to remove the signal handler in Component.onCompleted.

Also a quick question, why the window component completed faster than mouseArea? the log "first load" first loaded.

```
  MouseArea {
        id:mouse
        anchors.fill: parent
        Connections{
            onClicked:say()
        }
        Component.onCompleted: {
            //mouse.clicked.connect(say)
            console.log("second load")
        }
    }

    Component.onCompleted: {
        console.log("first load")
        mouse.clicked.connect(
                    function(){
                        mouse.clicked.disconnect(say);
                        //mouse.clicked.disconnect(say);
                        console.log("22222")
                    });

    }
```

Comment: Emm... Maybe this answer for that quick quesiton comes too late. The order of `Component.onCompleted` is undefined in qml.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can't disconnect the default signal handler `onSignal: { do what ever }`.

You can only dissconnect, when you have connected with `onSignal.connect(say)` beforehand. You could do this in `Component.onCompleted`.
If you use the syntax:

```
onSignal: say()
```

this equals

```
onSignal.connect(function() { say() })
```

and therefore you can't use `onSignal.disconnect(say)` as `say` was never connected. (I don't know whether it is connected to `onSignal` or to `signal` - both could be done manually, or whether it is not connected at all. You can't disconnect it, without having a reference to the implicitly created function.)

---

In QML, the nicer way would be to stay declarative. For this you can use the [`Connections`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html)-construct:

```
Connections {
    target: mouse // set to null to disconnect (Qt<=5.6)
    onClicked: { do what ever }
    enabled: true // change this, when you want to disconnect it (Qt>=5.7)
}
```

Comment: hi derM, Connections still doesn 't work, I tried it by using Qt5.6.1, there is no the property :enabled.

Comment: Oh, ok. I did not see, that this property was introduced in Qt5.7 (http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-connections.html#enabled-prop).

Comment: I added a comment to my code. You can set the `target` to `null` to deactivate the `Connection` in Qt5.6 and earlier.

Comment: @Chiron: I had to roll back your edit. To my understanding `onSignal: say()` equals to `onSignal.connect(function() { say() })` while `onSignal: say` equals to `onSignal.connect(say)`. `onSignal: say()` is the shorthand of `onSignal: { say() }`. See the example [here](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#property-change-signal-handlers). `onSignal: say()` does not invoke `say()` uppon creation of the binding. It is invoked when the surrounding (yet otherwise empty) block is invoked uppon fireing of the signal.

Answer (score 3):

You haven't used the explicit `connect()` function to begin with.  To `disconnect()` a function, it has to have been connected explicitly using `connect()`.

There is an example here that might help:

http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-signals.html#connecting-signals-to-methods-and-signals

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that as following:

```js
function connect(_signal, _slot) {
    var connectionFunc = () => {
        _slot.apply(this, arguments);
    }
    _signal.connect(connectionFunc);
    return connectionFunc;
}

// use some where like this
function doWork() {
    var conn = connect(btn.clicked, myFunc);
    // disconnect...
    btn.clicked.disconnect(conn);
}
```

another example for connecting once:

```js
function connectOnce(sig, slot) {
    var slotConnection = () => {
        slot.apply(this, arguments);    // run slot by passing `this` and arguments (as list).
        sig.disconnect(slotConnection); // disconnect slot :)
    }
    sig.connect(slotConnection);        // connecting slot to signal in Qt way
}
```