# Qt5, QML, how to deliver some signal from background thread to multiple windows

Tags: multithreading, qml, qt5

I'am working on a small Qt5 project that needs to communicate with a piece of hardware and signal more than one window. I create an object (a thread communicating with a device) in main function and "inject it" to the application engine using setContextProperty.

```
TestClass testClass;
    
QQmlApplicationEngine engine;
engine.rootContext()->setContextProperty("testClass", &testClass);
```

Then, the main window has access to testClass, can call slot functions and receive signals.

I need to open a new window on top of the first one (let's say with a button click) and start receiving the same signals. How to detach the signals from the first window and attach them to the second one? After closing the second window I need to process signals in the first window again. How to achieve this scenario?

Comment: [Signal & slots](https://doc.qt.io/qt-6/signalsandslots.html) mechanism does exactly what you need.

Comment: I would keep the signal connected in the main windows and just check if the second window is not open before processing the signal further. You should show how you open the second window for us to understand if the signal is available there

Comment: Thank you for a hint. So it sounds like to implement some logic and just ignore incoming data in the main window if the second one is open.

Comment: You can disconnect your signal. See it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44496742/how-to-disconnect-the-method-for-a-signal-in-qml)

Answer (score 0):

You mentioned that your already connected your C++ to QML and you are already receiving the signals in QML.

Therefore, all we need to do is deliver the message to the correct window. If I interpret your requirement correctly, you actually do not want to broadcast to all windows. You only want to determine the top most window and ensure that window receives it and that the top most window can change whilst the application is running, but, you will always have one destination window.

In the following, I've mocked up `FirstPage.qml` and `SecondPage.qml` and have made use of `StackView` to host both. I do this, because the `StackView` has a convenient `currentItem` property I can use it to determine the top most page. So, you can happily push/pop to the `StackView` so that there is always exactly one destination page that will receive the message.

You can use this idea as-is, or implement your own Javascript array that simulates a stack and as your windows appear/disappear, you push/pop a reference to that window to that Javascript array. Again, you can use that array to determine the top-level window and ensure exactly one copy of your message is being delivered.

Below, I use a `Timer` to simulate the messages, and I broadcast it to the top-level `currentItem` in my `StackView`:

```
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    function sendMessage(msg) {
        stackView.currentItem.receiveMessage(msg);
    }
    StackView {
        id: stackView
        anchors.fill: parent
        initialItem: "FirstPage.qml"
    }
    Timer {
        id: timer
        property int mid: 0
        interval: 1000
        running: true
        repeat: true
        onTriggered: sendMessage(`message ${++mid}`)
    }
}

// FirstPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    header: Text { text: "FirstPage.qml" }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel { id: mainListModel }
        delegate: Label { text: msg }
    }
    function receiveMessage(msg) {
        mainListModel.append( {msg} );
    }
    footer: Frame {
        Button {
            text: "SecondPage"
            onClicked: stackView.push("SecondPage.qml")
        }
    }
}

// SecondPage.qml
import QtQuick
import QtQuick.Controls
Page {
    header: Text { text: "SecondPage.qml" }
    ListView {
        anchors.fill: parent
        model: ListModel { id: secondListModel }
        delegate: Label { text: msg }
    }
    function receiveMessage(msg) {
        secondListModel.append( {msg} );
    }
    footer: Frame {
        Button {
            text: "Back"
            onClicked: stackView.pop()
        }
    }
}
```

You can [Try it Online!](https://stephenquan.github.io/qmlonline/?zcode=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)

Comment: Thank you very much for grate example. For now I ended up using stack view connecting each page to service class (communicating with device) and processing signal only if the page is active - simple and seems to work fine.